# Merge multiple lists in a list with loop function

Tags: r

I have 4 datasets that contains the same var called "siteid_public". The ultimate goal is: I want to see how many unique "siteid_public" in this four datasets. I will add them together and then use length (unique()) to get the number.

I use very stupid way to get this goal,the code like this:

```
site1<-dflist[[1]]%>%
  select(siteid_public)
site2<-dflist[[2]]%>%
  select(siteid_public)
site3<-dflist[[3]]%>%
  select(siteid_public)
site4<-dflist[[4]]%>%
  select(siteid_public)
site<-c(site1$siteid_public, site2$siteid_public,site3$siteid_public,site4$siteid_public)
length(unique(site))
```

But now, I want to improve its efficiency.

So, first, I use this code to create a list called "sitelist" which contains 4 lists coming from for datasets.(The dflist[[i]] in the code is the place where I store these 4 datasets.) After I run the code below, each list has one same var called siteid_public. The code is here:

```
sitelist<-list()
for (i in 1:4){
 sitelist[[i]]<-dflist[[i]]%>%
  select(siteid_public) 
}
```

Now I want to add all 4 lists in sitelist as one list, and then use unique to see how many unique siteid_public value in this combined list. Could people help me to continue this code and achieve that goal? thanks a lot~~!

Comment: `unique(unlist(lapply(dflist, function(z) select (z, siteid_public))))`

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, another following question is what if I only want to check the siteid_public in specific datasets (such as dflist[[2]] and dflist[[4]]) ?

Comment: `lapply(dflist[c(2,4)], ...)` works as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to iterate on a [list of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227), either on the whole list or just as easily a subset (including one or zero).

Your `site1` through `site4` can be created as a *list* with

```r
sites <- lapply(dflist[1:4], function(z) select(z, siteid_public))
```

and you can do your unique-counting with

```r
unique(unlist(sites))
```

This works as well with

```r
sites <- lapply(dflist, ...)     # all of it
sites <- lapply(dflist[3], ...)  # singleton, note not the `[[` index operator

indices <- ...                   # integer or logical of indices to include
sites <- lapply(dflist[indices], ...)
```